# trying to format gt tables, unable to use function ```md```

Tags: r, markdown, gt

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0UGmMOxl-c to learn to us gt, and running into the problem that using `md(` to change fonts is not working as he shows. i'm running the code exactly as he shows in the first few minutes, but nothing happens. is there a package i need to download? a function i need to create?

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(markdown)

penguins%>%
  group_by(species) %>%
summarize_at(
  .vars= c("bill_length_mm",
           "bill_length_mm",
           "flipper_length_mm",
           "body_mass_g"
           ),
  .funs= ~ mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)
  )%>%
  gt(rowname_col = "species")%>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("The *penguins* dataset"),
    subtitle = md("three years of data on penguins on on ***three islands***")
  ) 
  )%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align="left")
```

furthermore, when i tried to follow his instructions for `cols_label` i got `Error: C stack usage  15923456 is too close to the limit`

```
penguins%>%
  group_by(species) %>%
summarize_at(
  .vars= c("bill_length_mm",
           "bill_length_mm",
           "flipper_length_mm",
           "body_mass_g"
           ),
  .funs= ~ mean(.,na.rm=TRUE)
  )%>%
  gt(rowname_col = "species")%>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("The *penguins* dataset"),
    subtitle = md("three years of data on penguins on on ***three islands***")
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    bill_length_mm=md("Bill Length, <br>mm")
  )%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align="left")
```

(second command from bottom)

Comment: Both the code chunks are working fine for me.  Please check your package versions

Comment: wow, yup, that's all there was to it...